# pinescript - Query the point where 2 lines meet

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I would like to query the meeting of 2 lines on a candlestick. The way I see it, the two lines that are formed via line.new should have the same values at this point. Unfortunately, I was not able to create a query for this case. Hence the question how should the query be implemented in order to query the meeting of two lines on a candlestick?

[image: Here's a picture]

Comment: Why not keep track of those bars as you create new lines?